# Duplicate Data POST

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core

When I try to post a form, I want to avoid duplicate post of same data through backend. I tried using session and storing the unique GUID for mapping if the posted is duplicate or not. If you have faced same problem or have the answer. Please help me.

Comment: It happens on some form submit due to slow pc or slow internet connection. I want to avoid it from backend, by using action validation filter.

Answer (score 1):

**if you want avoid form submissions like if might robot submitting forms then **

we have to set one unique token on form then while submit the form pass that token and save it to database.

when second time form will submit event occur from the same token consider that hit is malicious.

```
<form id="xyz">
<input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="unique Value">
<submit button>
</form>
```

on backend you can save this token into Session or anywhere you want but check same token
is already exist in session or **DataBase** or not.

I prefer save tokens to DB if we need to check data as well. else we can restrict same form submission by robot or anyone else.

or you can share your code so we can help you.

Comment: I think saving tokens in database would help. Thank you for your answer. Also if you know some other way, can you add that too.